# What is the maximum amount of downvotes for one user's questions/answers by another user?

Tags: support, down-votes

In my previous question I did not get my answer and instead of it I have been suspended and did not get the reason. I think it was to make cool down mods and some other users who are angry about my questions however I cannot find why a question can make the others angry! There is no insult or wrong request in my questions unless to guide me how I can use my right in voting like the others to some questions which are wrong or are non constructive in my own opinion. I hope you are relax now and can read my questions in peace! :)

How many times can I down vote questions of one user( I think it is clear which I do not mean downvoting to one user not his/her questions on purpose but his/her trivial question/answers by accident!) ? Please consider that I am not able to read minds of mods and find their tastes! I need rules in FAQ to show me how many times for example after 5 times I cannot downvote to questions of one user and if I try it I will be suspended unless I am a mod or I am trying it in one week with some rests not in one hour!

To make it easier:

Which of following answers are correct about this question:

1. One time.
2. Two times and less.
3. Three times and less.
4. Five times and less.
5. It depends on whom you are downvoting!
6. It depends on the mods imagination and the case.
7. It is in the FAQ!

I hope to get a very clear and related answer in short sentences. Long-winded answers make me confused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And I was just thinking of who and why recently downvoted my last questions on History and Meta... I should know that the answer is quite obvious, somebody's just testing how many downvotes for one user are still OK. ;]

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski [Voting on Meta works a bit differently](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences), we are far more liberal with downvotes (and upvotes) than on the main site.

Comment: @YannisRizos thanks :)

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski :)) I confess that I like to downvote your questions but it was not in my serial downvoting plan! Now I know I have to wait for some days between my downvotes as I have not the same chance like you and some who are killing my questions and answers by downvoting!

Comment: @YannisRizos I disagree as I found myself suspended in one of main sites only because I defended of myself in front of an Italian fascist user who insulted my nationality and has powerful protection by some mods of this site. She/he is following me in beta sites and is giving me his/her ridiculous comments and downvotes even in arena 51 to me! She/he is a perfect flatter and ass-leach, such thing that I cannot be! She/he is doing his/her job against me in a noble cause which is according to her/his racist/fascist ideas in one of beta sites too!

Comment: @user37324 If you think the moderators are conspiring with a user against you, please contact Stack Exchange directly through the "contact us" link in the footer.

Comment: It is interesting for me that being a feminist,Iranian and owner of an independent personality is all against unreadable rules of this site and they can use serial downvoting against me to keep my votes in a safe range but if I try the same they can suspend me according to ideas of 3 or 4 mods who are mods because of some votes and it is interesting to know that fascist user is going to be one of mods too!!! It is interesting for me that how it can be absurd to find a fairly democratic space in cyber world! It is impossible!

Comment: @YannisRizos I used it once and nothing unless becoming suspended again! :)

Answer (score 6):

> How many times can I down vote questions of one user?

You shouldn't be looking to downvote questions of one user, this is just plain wrong and I imagine the reason you were suspended. Please do not target specific users with your votes (up or down), instead vote for posts. You shouldn't care at all who the author of the post is, the only thing you should care about is how helpful and well researched the post is.

Furthermore, the mechanics of the serial voting script are intentionally kept vague to prevent people from gaming the system. If you knew that you could downvote another user's posts `x` times per day and get away with it, then what's stopping you from downvoting `x` posts every day for ever?

What I can tell you is that the rules are the same for everyone, on every Stack Exchange site. It doesn't depend on whom you are downvoting or on the mods' imagination, there is an automated process that detects serial voting, and it runs the same checks on everyone's account.

I am a moderator on two Stack Exchange sites and [I was caught by the script once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoters), having a diamond (or two) and lots of rep is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry! I am not looking for serial downvoting but I am target of this phenomenon myself and it is obvious if you look at my questions and answers and their votes! I asked how many times can I downvote questions from one user ( Accidentally there are some trivial questions all have made by one user! ) and not make mods pessimist about my motivation?! I hope it helps! :)

Comment: @user37324 If you are a target of serial downvoting, the downvotes will be automatically reversed after 24 hours. If they are not reversed, then it's not a single user targeting you and the downvotes are legitimate. You asked how many times you can downvote questions from one user, and I'm answering that this is the wrong question to ask and if you don't avoid this mentality, you'll find yourself in trouble again. **Do not vote users, vote posts instead**.

Comment: I agree with Yannis, you should be voting based on **content**, and not based on **user**. If you feel you have been attacked or received downvotes that were not justified, then you can flag the post and use that to send a message to the mods. We will investigate and if we agree that the downvotes were **not** justified, then we can reverse them. However, if you choose to retaliate by downvoting multiple posts by one user, **your** votes will be flagged, regardless of your rep or the number of posts you have made.

Comment: Sorry but your logic is wrong because you are ignoring the matter of being new user as your system cannot show any serial downvoting some try it against new users because they do not have many questions to your reactions against them show any logical line! I DID NOT VOTE USERS BUT TRIVIAL POSTS WHICH WERE ACCIDENTALLY BY ONE USER BUT SOME HERE AND THERE ARE DOING IT AGAINST ME ON PURPOSE. I HAVE NOT 17 QUESTION SO YOUR SYSTEM DOESN'T SHOW A SERIAL DOWNVOTING AGAINST ME AND SOME ARE MISUSING IT. I hope it helps to get the matter in peace! :)

Answer (score 5):

> Which of following answers are correct about this question:

None of them. It's not about *who* you vote for, it's about *how* you vote.

You can find the canonical answer to this question [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/):

> As of today, we have several queries that look for unusual downvote patterns. If we discover these patterns in a given user’s voting history, we view all their downvotes for that user as suspect. They’re all silently deleted, and any lost reputation is restored to the unfortunate target of these downvotes.

In other words, it's the wrong question to be asking; if you need to know this, *you're doing it wrong.* Vote on the *content*, not the *person*. If you find yourself going through someone's profile down-voting everything they've written, stop and ask yourself:

- Is this person blatantly abusing the site by posting nothing but low-quality content? If so, **flag one of their posts for moderator attention** and explain the situation; they may need a talking-to.
- Have I become overly fixated on the personality of the person involved? Did they annoy me in some fashion, to where I'm now being exceptionally critical of their work vs. the work of others on the site? If so, **stop, walk *away* from your computer, and calm down.** You're not being objective, and this is likely skewing your voting.

Note that moderators can't see individual votes - only patterns. If a moderator is chiding you for abusive voting, chances are the system has detected something unusual in how you're casting your votes; if you do not heed their advice and adjust your behavior, you'll probably find your votes invalidated and possibly even your account suspended.

Comment: I did answer it in one sentence - read the first sentence I wrote.

Comment: The first sentence *I* wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "as many as you feel are needed **and** appropriate". We have suggested that you read the FAQ so that you would have a better understanding of what is appropriate and what reasons would justify the downvoting of a question or an answer.

Having said that, if we see that you are going through every question or answer that was posted by one individual, or by a small group of individuals, then we see that as an attack on that individual. You don't downvote posts because of the individual, you downvote them because of the content.

A very clear indication is an answer that has received 16 consecutive upvotes, and then suddenly receives one downvote. Then we observe that several other answers by the same individual, all with more than ten upvotes and no downvotes, start to receive single downvotes, and they are all from the same individual. I give this specific example because this actually happened (but I'm not saying it was you who did it).

Quite frankly, unless you are going through every Q&A on the site and downvoting only the ones that have already received multiple downvotes, you are going to be flagged. It doesn't matter if you use one or one hundred, if they are not justified, then you will be suspeneded again, and this time for a longer period.

Comment: There is no fixed number; it depends on us as mods interpreting the intent of your actions. You can place downvotes on posts as often as you like **as long as they are justified**. If you downvote only one person (or a small group), that WILL be viewed as an attack.

Comment: Sorry! But there is not anything in FAQ to show HOW MANY TIMES IN WHICH PERIOD OF TIME IT IS ALLOWED! Look at my question again! Can I ask you how can I find when you consider my downvote a real try and when a damaging try against author not question? And why there is not same thing about me and my questions? I think this kind of judgement can give a chance to a bad mod to take a revenge of a user. Who can give me a guarantee which this will never happen for me as I think it has happened for me by you in 3 sites! two beta and one main! :(

Comment: @StevenDrennon - too bad you're not the mod on SFF.SE :)

Comment: @DVK Oh and too bad that you are not his/her assistant! :))

Comment: Sorry I meant his assistant! I found it is a he by focusing on his photo! :\

Comment: @user37324 - I wouldn't make a good mod. I was actually offered that but turned down.

Comment: @DVK I cannot be a good mod too as I like to play more than manage. Do not worry! However no body suggested me to be a mod! :")